# Windows path to LocalTexFiles can't contain special characters with MikTex+Biber?

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber, windows

I am using Windows 10 (with WinEdt 9.1) + MikTex 2.9 + BibLaTeX 3.7.
My path (`D:\Usuários\Varios\LocalTexFiles`) contains special characters, which results in the below error.

The system is unable to find my `files.bib` and compilation stated:

> LaTeX Warning: Citation 'AA:##a' on page # undefined on input line ##.

The work around was to use another one, with no special characters: `D:\Users\Varios\LocalTexFiles` (in both cases, `bib` files contain only regular characters, e.g. `controle.bib`).

Do I have to stay with this work around or is there another way to fix this?

Comment: You can make a suitable bug report https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex. But I recommend to avoid file names and pathes with unusual chars (including spaces). It can save you a lot time.

Comment: It would help if you could go into more details about the errors you received. Explain what you did, what you expected and what happened instead. Please show the relevant `.log` files, console output or other warnings and errors. Did the problem occur with all documents, even the simplest "Hello World!" ones, or did you have to load other packages to provoke the error? (You mention `biblatex` explicitly, why?)

Comment: Non-US-ASCII chars are fine in the path as long as the file name does not contain non-ASCII chars. So `D:\Usuários\äölkßó\Documents\main.tex` would be OK, but `C:\Users\dimicamp\äß.tex` would not be OK. TeX mainly worked fine for me even with non-ASCII chars, but Biber indeed has problems in the latter case. This limitation is known to the Biber developer, but since it only poses a mild restriction on the possible file names not a lot of effort goes into improving the situation. Apparently file name handling on Windows is quite a bit more complicated than one would hope.

Comment: That doesn't show exact errors or full paths. Was it just the path or did the file name contain non-ASCII, too? In any case, the real answer is that avoiding special characters (spaces, accented characters etc.) in path and file names makes life much, much easier and is generally very easy to do. But it sounds as if the characters are probably OK in directory names, so long as you don't have them in file names. (If I understodd @moewe correctly.)

Comment: Please give the exact and full file names (if you don't want to do that to protect your privacy, please try to give equivalent names and make sure you have tested that the same issue arises). Please explain exactly which programmes you invoked and how. Ideally use the command line. If you use an editor please show us its configurations as well. Please explain your document set-up and where which files live.

Answer (score 2):

Let me share the results of my investigations.

In general it is best to avoid non-ASCII chars (and spaces) in file names that TeX and its helper programmes process. There are several places where things could go wrong for `biblatex` and Biber.

In my tests it was absolutely fine that the path excluding the basename of the `.tex` file contained non-ASCII chars

```
D:\Usuários\äölkßó\Documents\main.tex
```

would work absolutely fine if TeX and Biber were called from within the directory `D:\Usuários\äölkßó\Documents\`, i.e. only

```
pdflatex main
biber main
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

was executed. In that case TeX and friends don't have to worry about the rest of the path containing evil characters and will work just fine.

If the basename of the main `.tex` file contained non-ASCII chars, compilation failed on my Windows machine (Windows 10, MikteX 2.9), on a Linux virtual machine (Ubuntu 17.04, TeX live 2018) the example worked. This was independent of whether or not the rest of the path contained non-ASCII chars or not.
Of course this also applies if the working directory is different from the file location and the file has to be called with non-ASCII chars as in

```
biber ..\äölkßó\Documents\main
```

This would fail as well.

Additionally, and this was probably not part of your initial problem, `biblatex` can't handle non-ASCII chars in `\addbibresource` unless XeLateX or LuaLaTeX is used.

---

If things did not work for you in a `D:\Usuários\äölkßó\Documents\main.tex` situation I can only assume that your editor does not set the working directory to the file location and executes only `biber main`, but that it calls `biber` with the entire path. A workaround would be to try to make your editor change the working directory of its calls before its starts. (TeXworks does this on my machine)

---

The Biber developer is aware of the Windows problem with non-ASCII file names, but apparently a solution is quite tricky and a simple work-around is available (don't use non-ASCII chars), so the issue is not high priority. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/203

Comment: It doesn't change your good advice, but perhaps it's worth mentioning that (if I recall correctly, I'm a "long time no-Windows" user) the base `Usuários` is the default `Users` directory of a Portuguese Windows installation.